# alternative to @get_header[0] to check if a remote file exists

Tags: php

I am very new to php. Want to load css file of my plugin if the css file doesnot exist in the theme/my_plugin folder (i copy pasted the file).
to include if the file exists in the theme/my_plugin folder I am using @get_headers[0], what could be the alternative to it, which is simpler and easier.
I'm including it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php if( @get_headers( MY_THEME_PLUGIN_CSS . 'style-archive.css')[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
            echo set_url_scheme( MY_THEME_PLUGIN_CSS . 'style-archive.css') . MVERSION;
        } else {
            echo set_url_scheme( MY_PLUGIN_CSS . 'style-brochures-archive.css') . EPL_BR_CSS_VERSION;
        } ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

where MY_THEME_PLUGIN_CSS = my_theme/my_plugin/css/
and MY_PLUGIN_CSS = my_plugin/css

Please let me know how can I minimise the code and yet keep it simple

Comment: Why check for *remote* resources over HTTP, if those are actually *local* files?

Comment: yes, it's local in my case, but what if I have to access some remote file,
css is included using the url , not the path, so how to check for those files.

Comment: That's both completely pointless. Remote file checks just slow down PHP and page rendering. Also that's neither how graceful degradation works.